# Get started with Node.js in Windows

Tags: node.js

How should I get stated with Node.js on Windows? What dependencies do I need? What do I need to download? Do I need to type anything into the Command Prompt? Can I even use Node.js on Windows?

Comment: did you do any research?

Comment: So if you search "node.js", you can get the Node.js website! It's at http://nodejs.org/. See that big, green INSTALL button? Click it. Then, you can save the installer and double-click on it to run it. (Make sure to click twice *in rapid succession* if in Explorer. This is a common mistake.) Then follow the prompts.

Comment: Then you can run the Node.js REPL from the Start Menu, or open the command line and run things using `node`. If you have an aversion to the command line, go into the installation directory and make a shortcut to `node.exe` on your Desktop or somewhere! Then you can run Node.js scripts by dragging them onto the icon. Associating the file type to `node.exe` is also quite possible!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you have to do is download the Windows version:  http://www.nodejs.org/download/  Nothing more.

You can run it by typing `node` on the command prompt.  It even sets up the path for you.  It's that simple.

Comment: I've tried the MSI before, and it gave me an error, but now it works! Thanks!

Comment: How do I start the server?

Comment: @user1971491 Node doesn't have a pre-defined server that you can just start. It instead has modules available to help you create or define a server application yourself -- e.g., [`http`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html) and [`net`](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html). So, to start a server, you have to write a script that uses one of these modules and execute that script.